# PHP preg_match_all for YYYY/YY format

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to search year from a string

```
$file = 'Westwav 2014/15 ^30^0       £3,020.00 ';
```

Mostly it will be in the format of **YYYY/YY** , could any one tell me how to get the value of year in this format .

I have used something like

```
$file = 'Westwav 2014/15 ^30^0       £3,020.00 ';
$pattern = '/^[1-9]+\/[1-9]+$/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $file, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Required Output :**

2014/15

**Actual Output :**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) )
```

From that whole string $file , If I execute the above code it returns only the empty array . Could any one suggest me a preg_match_all to remove other suffs from the string and return only the year in YYYY/YY format .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: `^` means start of string and `$` means end of string. neither will match because your date is in the middle of your string. So get rid of those two

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you're looking for is `/(\d{4}\/\d{2})/`.
When you use it with `preg_match_all('/(\d{4}\/\d{2})/', $subject, $matches);`, the variable `$matches[1]` will contain all "years" from the string.